# Why this code doesn't create 10 lines in WPF?

Tags: wpf, shapes

I'm a beginner in WPF, I put below code in a button click handler, I expect there would be 10 vertical lines after clicking the button, but there's only one, any ideas? Thanks! And 'spDrawPanel' is a stackpanel.

```
        double aw = this.spDrawPanel.ActualWidth;
        double ah = this.spDrawPanel.ActualHeight;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Line ln = new Line();
            ln.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            ln.X1 = aw / 10 * i;
            ln.Y1 = ah;
            ln.X2 = aw / 10 * i;
            ln.Y2 = ah - 15;
            ln.StrokeThickness = 1;
            this.spDrawPanel.Children.Add(ln);
        }
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the debugger to verify that the spDrawPanel.Children collection actually has 10 children, and verify the X/Y coordinates of the resulting lines?

Comment: Yes,it has 10 children, and their x/y are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `StackPanel` which by default stacks each line [Verticaly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.orientation.aspx) from each other and you are starting at the **bottom** of the `StackPanel` and hence you are running out of real estate. Try setting Y1 to 15 and Y2 to 0 and you will get your 10 lines.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the problem is caused by StackPanel, I simply replace StackPanel with Canvas, and all works fine. Thanks a million.